# Find the first missing file in a series of numbered files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have directory containing files:

```
$> ls blender/output/celebAnim/
0100.png  0107.png  0114.png  0121.png  0128.png  0135.png  0142.png  0149.png  0156.png  0163.png  0170.png  0177.png  0184.png  0191.png  0198.png  0205.png  0212.png  0219.png  0226.png  0233.png  0240.png  0247.png  0254.png  0261.png  0268.png  0275.png  0282.png
0101.png  0108.png  0115.png  0122.png  0129.png  0136.png  0143.png  0150.png  0157.png  0164.png  0171.png  0178.png  0185.png  0192.png  0199.png  0206.png  0213.png  0220.png  0227.png  0234.png  0241.png  0248.png  0255.png  0262.png  0269.png  0276.png  0283.png
0102.png  0109.png  0116.png  0123.png  0130.png  0137.png  0144.png  0151.png  0158.png  0165.png  0172.png  0179.png  0186.png  0193.png  0200.png  0207.png  0214.png  0221.png  0228.png  0235.png  0242.png  0249.png  0256.png  0263.png  0270.png  0277.png  0284.png
0103.png  0110.png  0117.png  0124.png  0131.png  0138.png  0145.png  0152.png  0159.png  0166.png  0173.png  0180.png  0187.png  0194.png  0201.png  0208.png  0215.png  0222.png  0229.png  0236.png  0243.png  0250.png  0257.png  0264.png  0271.png  0278.png
0104.png  0111.png  0118.png  0125.png  0132.png  0139.png  0146.png  0153.png  0160.png  0167.png  0174.png  0181.png  0188.png  0195.png  0202.png  0209.png  0216.png  0223.png  0230.png  0237.png  0244.png  0251.png  0258.png  0265.png  0272.png  0279.png
0105.png  0112.png  0119.png  0126.png  0133.png  0140.png  0147.png  0154.png  0161.png  0168.png  0175.png  0182.png  0189.png  0196.png  0203.png  0210.png  0217.png  0224.png  0231.png  0238.png  0245.png  0252.png  0259.png  0266.png  0273.png  0280.png
0106.png  0113.png  0120.png  0127.png  0134.png  0141.png  0148.png  0155.png  0162.png  0169.png  0176.png  0183.png  0190.png  0197.png  0204.png  0211.png  0218.png  0225.png  0232.png  0239.png  0246.png  0253.png  0260.png  0267.png  0274.png  0281.png
```

For some script, I will need to find out what the number of the first missing file is. In the above output, it would be `0285.png`. However, it is also possible that files in between are missing. In the end, I am only interested in the number `285`, which is part of the file name.

This is part of recovery logic: The files should be created by the script, but this step can fail. Therefore I want to have a means to check which files are missing and try to create them in a second step.

This is what I got so far (from [how to extract part of a filename before '.' or before extension](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137775/how-to-extract-part-of-a-filename-before-or-before-extension)):

```
ls blender/output/celebAnim/ | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1}'
```

What I cannot figure out is how do I find the smallest number missing from that result, above a certain offset? The offset in this case is 100.

Comment: The number need not be `285` and can be any number `0100-0285` in general?

Comment: Yes. There is an overall range between 100 and 500. If all numbers are present, I am done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over all number from 100 to 500 and check if the corresponding file exists; if it doesn't, you'd print the number you're looking at:

```
for i in {100..500}; do
    [[ ! -f 0$i.png ]] && { echo "$i missing!"; break; }
done
```

This prints, for your example, `285 missing!`.

This solution could be made a bit more flexible by, for example, looping over zero padded numbers and then extracting the unpadded number:

```
for i in {0100..0500}; do
    [[ ! -f $i.png ]] && { echo "${i##*(0)} missing!"; break; }
done
```

This requires extended globs (`shopt -s extglob`) for the `*(0)` pattern ("zero or more repetitions of `0`").

Comment: Nice and concise. However if the upper and lower boundaries are defined as constants the for loop will not work. For that @Arash's proposal works better.

Answer (score 1):

```
begin=100
end=500
for i in `seq $begin 1 $end`; do
  fname="0"$i".png"
  if [ ! -f $fname ]; then
    echo "$fname is missing"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

search_dir=blender/output/celebAnim/

ls $search_dir > file_list

count=`wc -l file_list | awk '{ print $1 }'`

if [[ $count -eq 0 ]]
then
        echo "No files in given directory!"
        break
fi

file_extension=`head -1 file_list | tail -1 | awk -F "." '{ print $2 }'`
init_file_value=`head -1 file_list | tail -1 | awk -F "." '{ print $1 }'`
i=2

while [ $i -le $count ]
do
        next_file_value=`head -$i file_list | tail -1 | awk -F "." '{ print $1 }'`
        next_value=$((init_file_value+1));

        if [ $next_file_value -ne $next_value ]
        then
                echo $next_value"."$file_extension
                break
        fi

        init_file_value=$next_value;
        i=$((i+1));
done
```

Comment: Nice. However it  does miss some cases e.g. there is no or only one file at all.

Comment: Ya correct. I will edit it to add the corner cases. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
ls blender/output/celebAnim/ | sort -r | head -n1 | awk -F'.' '{print $1+1}'
```

command return `285`

if need return `0285` than try it:

```
ls blender/output/celebAnim/ | sort -r | head -n1 | awk -F'.' '{print 0($1+1)}'
```